# Shulchan Arukh, Even HaEzer 22:1

Tags: aruch-hashulchan

In this text, Shulchan Arukh, Even HaEzer 22:1, specifically at this passage:

> It is forbidden to isolate oneself with a person with whom sexual
> relations are prohibited, be they old or young. Such an action leads
> to uncovering nakedness

Does it refer to the araiyot, that is, the prohibited incestuous sexual relations, as specified by Maimonides in Mishneh Torah, Sefer Kedushah, Issurei Biah 21:1?

I don't understand what is meant, otherwise "It is forbidden to isolate yourself with a person with whom sexual relations are forbidden"

Or is it something different than incest?
Why does it specify old or young?

Comment: Not necessarily incestuous. It would apply to any married woman, for example. I think it specifies young or old to make clear it's not contingent on subjective sexual interest.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yichud